# Can we read Web.config values in XSD file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, web-config

**Can we read value from Web.config file in XSD ?**
Because my XSD-XML file validation is common for all clients except one value. So, I want to read client specific values from web.config in XSD.

Answer (score 0):

You must be validating your XSD-XML using some C# code. Use this code to manipulate the XSD based on config value and then proceed with validation.

Comment: Looks like a comment!